# How would you make a sticky header using this code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sticky

How would you make a sticky header using this code?

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
  color: #A3A3A3;
  height: 10%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 3%;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #A3A3A3;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="titlehomepage">
    <h1>GamingSocial</h1>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" style="text-decoration:none;">MENU</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="games.html" style="text-decoration:none;">GAMES</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="comingsoon.html" style="text-decoration:none;">NEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="comingsoon.html" style="text-decoration:none;">REVIEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="comingsoon.html" style="text-decoration:none;">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="sign-up.html" style="text-decoration:none;">SIGN UP</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is fixed already... what's the issue?

Comment: Well, you can describe, what have you tried and which one should be stocked, e.g. whole nav or only the unnumbered list, etc. Then you haven't to fill your question with random text.

Comment: well whe i i do this it goes like that http://prntscr.com/8b1cun

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue:

```
overflow: hidden;
height: 10%;
```

Do instead something like:

```
height: 300px; // or whatever value suits the height of the header
```